# IdentityServer3 Entity Framework migrate from v2 MembershipProvider

Tags: entity-framework, identityserver3

We use IdentityServer v2 in a production environment for over 2 years now. We'd like to move to v3 ou even 4, but I don't really see how we could migrate users account which are actually in a MembershipProvider DB to the new schema defined in the project `IdentityServer3.EntityFramework`. The problem is that I have no clue on how I could accomplish that. Anyone has ever done this ?

I don't see a scenario where I can add Scopes or Clients either. I guess that I have to create Scope object in code and save it to context, but since I'm not a pro in EF, I'm not really sure about the best practices. Can anyone point me to a sample ? The one in GitHub project doesn't seem to add Scopes or Clients, it just manage the schema with Migration (unless I'm mistaken).

EDIT : I got the sample working so I figured out the adding part in the Factory class. The Migration configuration part is explained [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/ef/migrations.html). There's a comment block in the ClientConfiguration Seed method where it shows how to use the AddOrUpdate extension. The Configuration class extends DbMigrationsConfiguration so you use it when you run the Update-Database command as the ConfigurationTypeName parameter.

So only question left is : how to update from MembershipProvider ?

Comment: Seen this? https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: No I didn't. That's a very good point ! If you put it in an answer I will accept it.